# CSS: How to use blend-mode and filter at once

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a image style I need to accomplish by taking a full color photo and:

1. Making it greyscale
2. Reducing black level (can be done by decreased opacity or brightness)
3. Applying "multiply" blend mode on top of blue color

So far I've only been able to do one of the other (multiply and greyscale OR opacity/levels)

Any idea how I could both of these on either an img element or background image?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/vENBqO

Current CSS:

```
body {
    margin:50px;
}

.test:parent {
    overflow:auto;
    background:#0c98f2;
    width:500px;
    height:320px;
}

.test {
    background-image:url(http://f.cl.ly/items/0z1I403f1a3O3v0o0l2b/PageImage-531144-5235316-finalselectsjared12.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-blend-mode:multiply,normal;
    background-color:#0c98f2;
    opacity:.5;
    width:500px;
    height:320px;
}

img {
    width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `blend-mode` require two background images? Anyway, filter works on inline images whereas blend mode works on bg images. The two properties don't interact as  they require different 'objects'. AFAIK

Comment: @Paulie_D Right right about the "objects" I guess I'm wanting to know if anyone has an idea on how to "hack" and make it work.

Comment: You can't hack two things that aren't the same. I think your objective outpaces CSS.

Comment: That said, perhaps what you need is actually an overlay - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YPyPgO?editors=010

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce all your steps in CSS, one by one

a) make it grayscale. apply the image over a black background, using luminosity as filter

b) reduce black level. apply a gray layer, with blend mode screen

c) apply a blue layer with mode multiply.

In the snippet, the b) step is done with a gradient, so you can see differents amounts of black reduction. (the lighter the gray, the bigger the effect)

```css
.demo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    background: linear-gradient(blue, blue), linear-gradient(90deg, black, gray), url("http://media.virbcdn.com/cdn_images/resize_1600x1600/4c/PageImage-531144-5235316-finalselectsjared12.jpg"); 
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: multiply, screen, luminosity;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></demo>
```